# Modelica image URI with placeholder for current package

Tags: image, uri, modelica, dymola

In a parameter dialogue of a Dymola/Modelica model I load an image with the code:

```
annotation (Dialog(group="Geometry", groupImage="modelica://my_package/image.png"));
```

My issue: as soon as I rename the package (or duplicate it into a new name) the image will not be found because the package name is hard-coded. Is there any placeholder syntax for the current package that model is sitting in, so that after renaming of the package the image is still found?